# C# event passthrough class to third level of classes

Tags: c#, events

Ok so here is my use case.

I have written an MMO server game engine, and the way I have it architected right now is mostly EDA. When the server receives a packet from a client, the core server publishes an event that other classes are subscribed to which carries the packet payload in the EventType e argument. The message has a header in the first bytes of the message, the first half of the byte carries bitwise information that determines which Class should pick up the message and do something with it, while the second half of the byte determines which method in the class needs to process the message.  And the classes that shouldn't process anything just drops it.

This evaluation is done through a series of if statements on each class, first asking...if (headervalue != myexpectedheader) return; ... for clarity, it's actually a double if (lessthan) || (morethan) return; because the set of header values that could belong to me is a range, because the first half of the byte addresses the class while the second half of the byte addressed the method, So the class can't really evaluate "what's mine" but rather "what's not mine" in order to keep that if statement at the top of the conditions set because it's more likely NOT MINE, than it is mine. This works just fine as is. The class that evaluates the header and determines the payload is for it, does so flawlessly, and the ones that shouldn't .. do not. I do not need help with this part, it was just asked that I explain it for others to understand.

Because this is an MMO server expected to recevied, process and respond to potentially several 1000s of users sending potentially hundreds of packets per second during network intensive activities, my concern is having a large number of classes performing condition evals for EVERY message received from untold numbers of clients.

Compound this with the fact that it is highly likely that 90 to 95% of the messages received should probably be picked up by one or two of the classes. So a LOT of system time will be wasted on evaluating "not for me" by every class, but also especially since 90% of the messages probably will go to the most used class.

I therefore am trying to build a message router that will subscribe to the incoming message event on the core server Class, perform the "which Class" condition evals just once for each message, and publish new events post-evaluation so that only the one or two other classes that really need to consume the event can subscribe to that new event and eliminate the untold numbers of wasteful evaluations that result in essentially " if (not for me) return;"

The scope of the question is really summed below, what's written above is not in scope for the actual question, it's just an explanation of how the evaluations are being conducted, and why this use case makes the question relevant.

I have a Class A which has a primary event. That event will fire off very rapidly. I have a high number of Class C's which need to potentially receive the information from Class A event. However because I have a high number of Class C subscribers, I want to create a Class B middle man as an event router to reduce the number of direct subscribers (and thus system overhead) to Class A

I want Class B to subscribe to Class A, and Class Cs to subscribe to Class B, with the final result that the correct Class C has effectively picked up the event from Class A.

I have already written the logic to sort the events, but I don't know how to write that pass through event so that Class C subscriber consumes the Class A Event by listening to the Class B event.

Comment: "to reduce the number of direct subscribers (and thus system overhead) to Class A" I don´t get that point. The number of subscribers is essentially the same, you only wrap them. Anyway subscribing to an event does not cause any system overhead. So what exactly is your concern here?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Ok so you are addressing the why, not the how, but that's ok. The why is the subscribers have code that evaluates whether they should respond to this event or not. That evaluation is done by satisfying 1 or 2 conditions. These conditions consume system resources. Having every subscriber performing the Me/NotMe eval is inefficient. Therefore, I want one listener that can do those evaluations one time, and publish an event to the correct subscriber(s). This is a use-case where efficiency is more important than readability or easiness of coding the solution.

Comment: If you have a high volume use case, I can see this making sense from an EDA perspective. I am just not sure how to pass the current contents of the event bus to a new distinct event, but maybe by extracting <Event> Args and wrapping them up into a fresh set of <Event> Args.

Comment: @ScotMcPherson Can you elaborate, on what your event sort logic looks like? Some example might help to understand your problem better

Comment: @treze I have updated the question for you, thanks.

Comment: Can there be overlapping ranges for a message/class? Or ranges are not overlapping, but there can be multiple event handlers (classes) sharing the same range?

Comment: @ScotMcPherson too bad this question is closed as the duplicate doesn't have the issue of doing some selection. Anyway, [reactive extensions](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive) might be a good fit. I created a [sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6g4XN2) that demonstration on how to create a stream of events and clients subscribing only to those events that are applicable to them.

Comment: @PeterBons thanks for the response. I really wish the moderators would open the question back up. This isn't really a duplicate question, and I think the intent of the question is misunderstood. It seems the question of WHY do this is more important the moderators than allowing answers for HOW TO do this. It's a shame stackexchange at large has become an environment where you need to provide justification for a question rather than just being able to ask the raw question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem correctly, but to start somewhere, here's an example of what I think you're asking for (see fiddle for a test run: https://dotnetfiddle.net/abEgV4):

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var source = new ClassA();
        var middleman = new ClassB(source);
        var subscribers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
            .Select(_ => new ClassC(middleman))
            .ToArray();
        
        Console.WriteLine("Fire 1!");
        source.FireEvent();
        Console.WriteLine("Fire 2!");
        source.FireEvent();
        Console.WriteLine("Fire 3!");
        source.FireEvent();
        Console.WriteLine("Fire 4!");
        source.FireEvent();
        Console.WriteLine("Fire 5!");
        source.FireEvent();
    }
}

class ClassA
{
    public delegate void SomeAEventHandler(object sender, string msg);
    public event SomeAEventHandler SomeAEvent;
    
    public void FireEvent()
    {
        SomeAEvent?.Invoke(this, "Event A fired");
    }
}

class ClassB
{
    public event ClassA.SomeAEventHandler SomeAEvent;
    private ClassA _eventSource;
    
    public ClassB(ClassA eventSource)
    {
        _eventSource = eventSource;
        eventSource.SomeAEvent += SomeAEventHappened;
    }
    
    private void SomeAEventHappened(object sender, string msg)
    {
        var rnd = new Random().Next(10);
        if (rnd % 2 == 0)
        {
            // Instead of 'this' use 'sender' if needed
            SomeAEvent?.Invoke(this, msg);
        }
    }
}

class ClassC
{
    private readonly ClassB _myMiddleman;
    public ClassC(ClassB middleman)
    {
        _myMiddleman = middleman;
        middleman.SomeAEvent += SomeAEventHappened;
    }
    
    private void SomeAEventHappened(object sender, string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassC got an event!");
    }
}
```

Does that cover the problem or can you elaborate on what's missing?

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have updated the question, maybe that will help you understand what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks.